# Using Views like tables in Entity Framework Code-first Existing database approach

Tags: entity-framework-6

I currently have a working WPF project that is using 2 tables from a sample Northwind database. Using Entity Framework code-first from an existing database these tables are displayed in master-detail format. I would like to use two views instead of the two tables.

I have found several tutorials and have implemented accordingly but for some reason I cannot get the dbcontext to read from the views. I created two views each matching the tables. I modified the class for the view to use [Table("vView")] and assigned a [Key] to create a primary key on the view but still no success. All research shows is to treat the view as if it was a table and all code should be the same. I am using Products and Categories table from Northwind database to test. I created their corresponding views vProducts and vCategories in the Northwind database.

Here is the code that works using the tables Products and Categories generated from the Entity Data Model (code-first):

Category.cs

```
namespace WPFCodeFirstExisting
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public class Category
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Category()
        {
            Products = new HashSet<Product>();
        }

        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(15)]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "image")]
        public byte[] Picture { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Products.cs

```
namespace WPFCodeFirstExisting
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public int? SupplierID { get; set; }

        public int? CategoryID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string QuantityPerUnit { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "money")]
        public decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }

        public short? UnitsInStock { get; set; }

        public short? UnitsOnOrder { get; set; }

        public short? ReorderLevel { get; set; }

        public bool Discontinued { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ProductContext.cs

```
namespace WPFCodeFirstExisting
{
    using System.Data.Entity;

    public partial class ProductContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProductContext()
            : base("name=ProductContext")
        {
           Database.SetInitializer<ProductContext>(null);
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .Property(e => e.UnitPrice)
                .HasPrecision(19, 4);
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindows.xaml.cs

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

```
public ProductContext _context = new ProductContext();        

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource categoriesViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("categoriesViewSource")));

    _context.Categories.Where(x => x.CategoryName.Contains("P")).Load();
    categoriesViewSource.Source = _context.Categories.Local;

 }
```

App.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProductContext" connectionString="data source=ABC;initial catalog=Northwind;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ProductContextView" connectionString="data source=ABC;initial catalog=Northwind;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Now if I modify the code to use 2 views instead:

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[vProducts]
SELECT * from [dbo].[vCategories]

these views just contain the select statement from their respective tables.

vCategory.cs:

```
namespace WPFCodeFirstExisting
{

    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    [Table("vCategories")]
    public class vCategory
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public vCategory()
        {
            vProducts = new HashSet<vProduct>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(15)]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "image")]
        public byte[] Picture { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<vProduct> vProducts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

vProducts.cs:

```
namespace WPFCodeFirstExisting
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    [Table("vProducts")]
    public class vProduct
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public int? SupplierID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
        public int? CategoryID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string QuantityPerUnit { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "money")]
        public decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }

        public short? UnitsInStock { get; set; }

        public short? UnitsOnOrder { get; set; }

        public short? ReorderLevel { get; set; }

        public bool Discontinued { get; set; }

        public virtual vCategory vCategory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ProductContextView.cs

```
namespace WPFCodeFirstExisting
{
    using System.Data.Entity;

    public class ProductContextView : DbContext
    {
        public ProductContextView()
            : base("name=ProductContextView")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ProductContextView>(null);
        }

        public  DbSet<vCategory> vCategories { get; set; }
        public  DbSet<vProduct> vProducts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<vProduct>()
                .Property(e => e.UnitPrice)
                .HasPrecision(19, 4);
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ProductContextView _context = new ProductContextView();

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource categoriesViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("categoriesViewSource")));

    _context.vCategories.Where(x => x.CategoryName.Contains("P")).Load();
    categoriesViewSource.Source = _context.vCategories.Local;

}
```

When I run using the ProductContextView, These lines do not return any data;

```
_context.vCategories.Where(x => x.CategoryName.Contains("P")).Load();
            categoriesViewSource.Source = _context.vCategories.Local;
```

I even tried doing something very simple like the following:

```
    var prods = _context.Database.SqlQuery<vCategory>("Select * from dbo.vCategories");
    foreach (var p in prods)
    {
        string test = p.CategoryName.ToString();
    }
```

but prods doesn't return any data either. This test works perfectly fine when using the tables.

I'm hoping to just replace the tables with views using EF. I do not want to use any CRUD operations with the views they are fine being read-only.

Comment: You should map the table classes to the views. There's no need for the view classes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you give me an example please? In the real application I will not have access to the tables.

Comment: [Table("vProducts")]

Comment: above public class Product?

Comment: Yes that's the idea

Comment: This worked. How do I accept the answer?

Comment: Well, I don't consider this a full answer. You have to decide what to do with migrations and the views must meet certain criteria if you want them to be updatable. If you only read from the views and don't use migrations, simply mapping the classes to the views is enough.

Comment: Views just will be read-only. No CRUD operation required, so the answer will suffice. Thank you again for your succinct and quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

What I found is that in code-first if you add a class representing a view as dbSet when the database is seeded it will create what you want to be a view as a table (probably why you are getting no results).

A work around is to create a custom an initializer :

```
public class CustomDBInitializer :  CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ProductContextView>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ProductContextView context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

Then after the base seed method use...

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()
```

...to drop the generated tables and run a SQL script that generates the views to replace them.

You can then use the dbset like a table but it will actually be using the view.

Also not sure why you created to separate contexts.